# Cannot get vertical scroll bar to show on iframe

Tags: html, iframe

I have embedded two iframes in a page. The page is used to input product numbers and search for specific products. The bottom iframe shows up with a vertical scroll bar when a number is input and results are returned. However, the top iframe will not show a vertical scrollbar despite having virtually the same code.

The page that I am working on is http://www.gleicher.com/die-cut/us-govt-nsn-and-fedspec-locators/. I am viewing the page in Google Chrome.

I have been using the code 898 for testing as the 3M Product Number in each iframe.

The code that I have used for the top iframe is below:

```
<div style="overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: scroll; margin: 15px auto; max-width:      1101px; width: 595px;"><iframe height="240" id="img-1403803668272" scrolling="yes" src="http://solutions.3m.com/wps/portal/3M/en_US/GovernmentSolutions/Home/ProductInformation/NSN_Locator/" style="border: 0px; margin-left: -230px; height: 655px; margin-top: -400px; width: 1000px;" width="320"></iframe></div>
```

I do not have access to the website that is the source of the iframe. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
   <div style="overflow: auto ; overflow-x: hidden; margin: 15px auto; max-width:     1101px; width: 595px;" > <!--Your stuff here --> </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried this, but it did not work. I am confused as to why the scrollbar shows up for the bottom iframe, but not the top one since the code is virtually the same